# Asset catalog iOS pdf vector how to use as source

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, asset-catalog

I'm trying to add images to the iOS project of my SCL following the new "apple way". I added a new asset images catalog to the iOS project and a new vector image to pdf format. The doc says it will automatically generates according images at compile time but I don't see any images.

I already have asset catalog for appIcon and launchImages, and its working well. I noticed that I don't have a line referencing the new added catalog of images in the info.plist.

How can I load it (I thought it would do it alone) properly ? What's the syntax to refer to it in info.plist ?

Final question : Can I use the vector image in my project as a source for image of xamarin forms like I do now to refer to Android images stored in Resources => Image ="imageName" . Or should I use .png images like the old way to use the same reference in my SCL project ?

I want to load an Image for pin on map and I thought pdf file will help me to solve resolution probs for iOS project (As I can't figure out what resolution to use to get a nice image on iOS, its always too small or too big using x1 x2 x3 compared to my Android proj).

I've been following the doc presented here : https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/working_with_images/displaying-an-image/#asset-catalogs

Thanks.

Comment: "I noticed that I don't have a line referencing the new added catalog of images in the info.plist." You don't need one. Any asset catalog that is part of the built app will be searched when an image is referred to in the usual ways, e.g. by calling `UIImage(named:)`. And the icon and launch images in the asset catalog designated when you edit the app target are written out to top level or referred to in the built info.plist (even though they are not referred to in _your_ info.plist).

Comment: Still I dont understand how I can use built in Image from Xamarin forms with that image asset. 
var image = new Image{ Source = "ic_home_black"}